# How to make a callback after the view is completely rendered?

Tags: java, android, view, callback

How to make a callback after the view is completely rendered ?

I am trying to call a method which takes a screen-shot of parent view.
If I write that code in `onCreate()` method, the app crashes due to null pointer (as no view is rendered).
for now the temporary solution I have implemented is to make a delay of 1 second before calling that method.
But, I am looking for a much more robust solution to this problem.

any suggestions and help appreciated.
thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean by View? A particular `View` or the entire `Activity`?

Comment: EDIT: I mean the entire activity.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11447417/884674 link for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got a better option now :)
this really gives a call-back after the layout is rendered

```
private class LoadActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mainMethod();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        takeScreenShot(1);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    };
}
```

I created the above class and then called this method for execution in onCreate()

```
LoadActivity loadactivity= new LoadActivity();
loadactivity.execute();
```

Comment: Wait ... how do you know that this won't run until after your app has been displayed?

Comment: why is that option better than the onWindowFocusChanged answer?

Comment: onWindowFocusChanged() keeps on getting called multiple times.

Comment: In Android 4.0.3 this seems to work, however, the view has not yet been rendered in the onPostExecute() method when I try this on Android 2.3.5

Answer (score 16):

Try this logic ... always called after the view has got focus or rendered or looses focus

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    doWhateverAfterScreenViewIsRendered();
}
```

Comment: thanks, this solved half of my problem. but, now another issue is that this method is"Called when the current Window of the activity gains or loses focus. " so I am getting 2 screenshots...

Comment: +1. I think this can be called multiple times, if you for instance show dialogs or such from your Activity, so the best idea would be maybe to keep a boolean flag on your Activity, `screenshotTaken`, and once you take the screenshot, set this to `true` and avoid creating extra files when `onWindowsFocushChanged` triggers again.

Comment: Thank you!  Simple and seems to work without a hitch. Just what the doctor ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29) callback on your `Activity`, which is

> Called when the activity will start interacting with the user. At this point your activity is at the top of the activity stack, with user input going to it.

Comment: hmm... I tried that. It's still the same. Only some sort of callback could help.

Comment: This will not do what you want. onCreate() sends messages for the rendering to happen, but the Activity does not wait for that rendering to _actually happen_ before it moves to onResume().  You will likely get null pointers if you try this approach as well; actually, it sounds like you did.

Comment: Matt is right: if you break into the onResume() method, you will see that the view is not showing up on the screen yet.