# Run long task on glThread without blocking UI thread on Android

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, surfaceview

I have to run through a lot of initialisation before I can render anything in my `GLSurfaceView`

Theses must be done on the OpenGL thread.

However this hangs my main thread for the duration of the initialisation.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FrameLayout renderingLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.movie_rendering_layout);
    if (renderingLayout != null && mGLView == null) {
        mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(getApplicationContext());
        /** [..] **/
        renderingLayout.addView(mGLView, params);
    }
}

/*--------------- OPENGL RELATED ---------------*/

protected class MyGLSurfaceView  extends GLSurfaceView {

    private final MyGLRenderer mRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Create an OpenGL ES 1.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
        mRenderer = new MyGLRenderer();
        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView
        setRenderer(mRenderer);
    }
}


protected class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private int mWidth, mHeight = 0;
    private boolean isFinished = false;


    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
       GLES10.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        init(mMovieIndex, AssetsUtils.getBinPath(getApplicationContext())); // <----- THIS takes long time

    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 pGL10) {

        GLES10.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GLES10.glClear(GLES10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        /* [...] */
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual answer is to create two EGL contexts in the same share group, each bound to a separate thread.

The main thread in the rendering loop does any rendering to screen, which during resource loading is normally something "boring" - i.e. a loading graphic, a progress bar, etc.

The second thread loads any bulk resources in the background, e.g. loading texture files, model meshes, etc and uploading them.

Once loading has completed the main thread can use all of the data resources loaded by the secondary async loading thread.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution:

The issue is that you must not block in `onDrawFrame` or `onSurfaceCreated`, since they are called synchronously by the main thread.

To disable the calls, I used in my surface constructor:

```
setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

This way, the calls to `onDrawFrame` will stop once the view is settled.

I performed the initialisation from

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
```

Be careful it can be called twice. If anyone has a better suggestion I'd gladly listen to it (taken from [How to make a callback after the view is completely rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393986/how-to-make-a-callback-after-the-view-is-completely-rendered))

I also overrided

```
@Override
public boolean isDirty()
   return false;
}
```

And don't forget to use `queueEvent` to run code on the GLThread